# Inheriting subclasses can not use Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtcore

I have a big problem with my classes: I will use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in my subclasses. But if I define `Q_OBJECT` in my subclasses, it throws an exception. This is the exception:

```
undefined reference to `vtable for SubClassOne'
undefined reference to `vtable for SubClassTwo'
```

My `SubClassOne` and `SubClassTwo` inherits from `BaseClass`.

Here some Code: (All `#include`s are correct)

```
\\baseclass.h
class BaseClass
{
public:
BaseClass(QWidget *widget=0);
QHBoxLayout *mainLayout;
};

\\subclassone.h
class SubClassOne : public BaseClass, public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit SubClassOne(QWidget *widget=0);
};

\\subclasstwo.h
class SubClassTwo : public BaseClass, public QDialog
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SubClassTwo(QWidget *dialog=0);
};
```

Here comes the .cpp Files

```
//baseclass.cpp
BaseClass::BaseClass(QWidget *widget)
{
 mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
}

//subclassone.cpp
SubClassOne::SubClassOne(QWidget *widget):BaseClass(widget)
{
 setWindowTitle("Widget");
}

//subclasstwo.cpp
SubClassTwo::SubClassTwo(QWidget *dialog):BaseClass(dialog)
{
setWindowTitle("Dialog");

QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton();
QObject::connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(close()));
mainLayout->addWidget(btn);
setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
SubClassTwo *s = new SubClassTwo();
s->show();
return a.exec();
}
```

How can I use `Q_OBJECT` in my subclasses?

Comment: 3) are you running the moc on the headers

Comment: Also, `QObject` (or the base class derived from `QObject`) must be the **first one** in the base class list. And you cannot inherit `QObject` multiple times, or virtually.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i forgott it, have edit my post, can you give me an example for include ..moc file? Using Qt5

Comment: @Angew: that is not true for Qt 5...

Comment: @LaszloPapp Good riddance! Thanks for the info. I'm stuck with Qt4 for now, but at least I'll know there's light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: @Angew: :-) moc is getting a lot of improvement in Qt 5, especially with C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Q_OBJECT placement is fine in your code.

What you are hitting is that you forgot to include the generated moc file in your source such as:

#### baseclass.cpp (at the end of the file)

```
#include "baseclass.moc"
```

#### subclassone.cpp (at the end of the file)

```
#include "subclassone.moc"
```

#### subclasstwo.cpp (at the end of the file)

```
#include "subclasstwo.moc"
```

You need to make sure moc is generating these files for you though. You have not shown your buildsystem yet.

Also, please make sure to have one header and source file per "Q_OBJECT" classes. It is not strictly necessary, but it is a good practice.

You can of course resolve that at link time as well, but you will need to do either of those.

Moreover, once you have multiple inheritance, at least with Qt 4, you will need to inherit from the `QObject` subclass first, which is `QWidget` in your case. You can find the correct inheritance below.

#### subclassone.h

```
class SubClassOne : public QWidget, public BaseClass
```

#### subclasstwo.h

```
class SubClassTwo : public QDialog, public BaseClass
```

etc. Hope it helps.

Comment: you can have moc create a `moc_foo.cpp` and compile and link that separately

Comment: @ratchetfreak: yes, but he did not do that either, apparently.

Comment: `no such file or directory foo.moc`

Comment: @user2372976: because you need the real file names, see my updated post before your comment.

Comment: okey, but normally my superclass inherit from qwidget and this superclass can use Q_OBJECT makro. Subclass can use it too. Maybe its better to change the Structure of my classes?

Comment: @user2372976: Q_OBJECT is not inherited, so you would need to specify that explicitly. As for that, my answer provides a designed solution.

Comment: @user2372976: That is an old and obsolete page. Please use this one: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html

Answer (score 0):

`Q_OBJECT` must be the firs declaration in your class and any class inheriting QObject must be first in the list

```
class SubClassOne : public QWidget, public BaseClass
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit SubClassOne(QWidget *widget=0);
};

\\subclasstwo.h
class SubClassTwo : public QDialog, public BaseClass
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SubClassTwo(QWidget *dialog=0);
};
```

you also need to run the moc on the header to generate the code needed to implement the slots and signals